# HC-05 sending data to Android a value but it cracked out of its form

Tags: arduino-uno, bluetooth, hc-05, android

I am totally beginner but I am trying to finish my project as school work :-(
but from the beginning, I am really stuck.

Could anyone help me out?

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial BTserial(10, 11); // RX | TX

void setup() {
  // initialize serial communication at 9600 bits per second:
  BTserial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  // read the input on analog pin 0:
  int sensorValue1 = analogRead(A0);
  int sensorValue2 = analogRead(A1);
  BTserial.print(sensorValue1);
  BTserial.print('|');
  BTserial.println(sensorValue2);
  delay(50);
}
```

The received value is here

```
D/BluetoothConnectionSrv: InputStream: 955|108
D/BluetoothConnectionSrv: InputStream: 9
D/BluetoothConnectionSrv: InputStream: 46|51
D/BluetoothConnectionSrv: InputStream: 9
D/BluetoothConnectionSrv: InputStream: 47|57
```

I need only values from 2 sensors, it seems to be as
    D/BluetoothConnectionSrv: InputStream: 955|108
    D/BluetoothConnectionSrv: InputStream: 946|51
    D/BluetoothConnectionSrv: InputStream: 947|57

I've tried to send "How are you?", then the result in the app was this

```
D/BF: o
D/BF: u ?Are yo
D/BF: u ?
D/BF: H
D/BF: ow Are you
D/BF:  ?
```

Source code in my app

```
        bluetoothSocket = socket;
        InputStream tempIn = null;
        OutputStream tempOut = null;

        try {
            tempIn = bluetoothSocket.getInputStream();
            tempOut = bluetoothSocket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        inputStream = tempIn;
        outputStream = tempOut;
    }

    public void run(){
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bytes;

        while(true){
            try {
                bytes = inputStream.read(buffer);
                handler.obtainMessage(STATE_MESSAGE_RECEIVED, bytes, -1, buffer).sendToTarget();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

---

```
            case STATE_MESSAGE_RECEIVED:
                byte[] readBuff = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                String tempMsg = new String(readBuff, 0, msg.arg1);
                tvMessage.setText(tempMsg);
                Log.d("BF",tempMsg);
                break;
```

Comment: it could be caused by the android app ....... one thing you could try with your program is to change the `BTserial.println` command to `BTserial.print`

Comment: That extra number is probably associated to `println` where it appends a new line character, although CR/LF should be 0x0D/0x0A...